# C# function with variable number of arguments causes confusion when multiple overloads available

Tags: c#, overloading, params-keyword

```
    public string GetErrorMessage(params object[] args)
    {
        return GetErrorMessage("{0} must be less than {1}", args);
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage(string message, params object[] args)
    {
        return String.Format(message, args);
    }
```

Here is the call

```
    Console.WriteLine(GetErrorMessage("Ticket Count", 5));
```

**Output**

```
Ticket Count
```

This means, it invokes the 2nd overload of the method with 2 parameters: message, variable number of object arguments.

Is there a way to force it to invoke first overload rather than second?

Comment: No. The second overload is a better match, and preferred because it avoids the overhead of creating the parameter array. Why do you provide both unless you *want* the second to be called in cases where it can be?

Comment: The one has default error message, which makes it handy for the consumer. I can't get rid of any, as both are intended to be invoked.

Comment: Well, the error message you've shown only has two placeholders, so why not change the convenience declaration to take only two parameters? Make them type `object` if you like, or use a generic method.

Comment: For other particular validations, the number of arguments may go to 3 for range validation with name, min & max values. Group validation where the number may go even beyond, when we want to say any of these properties must be entered. And, this is just the extracted simplified version of the code so you may not be able to see the complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is caused because the first item in your method call is a `string` and therefore will alway match the second method call. You can do 1 of the following to get around the problem:

If the order of the args is not important you could simply make sure that the first item is not a `string`:

```
this.GetErrorMessage(5, "Ticket Count");
```

Or you can cast the `string` to an `object`:

```
this.GetErrorMessage((object)"Ticket Count", 5);
```

You could always make this call however it does break the whole purpose of using `params`:

```
this.GetErrorMessage(new object[] {"Ticket Count", 5 });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Console.WriteLine(GetErrorMessage(new object[] { "Ticket Count", 5 }));
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote considering this directly answers the question "Is there a way to force it to invoke first overload rather than second?"

Comment: This answer is correct. I've checked it. But I think it's better if you give some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to take full advantage of the `params` keyword for the situation you are describing.  The compiler sees a more specific, better fit during overload resolution because of the string argument provided.  So the only way to force it into the first form is to explicitly force the string into an `object []`.  Something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetErrorMessage(new object[] { "Ticket Count", 5 }));
```

Comment: You can take advantage of the `params` keyword if you cast the first `string` to `object`. Not ideal but it still allows the use of `params` if it is needed.